# Getting maven error while running mvn clean install?

Tags: java, maven, crawler4j

I ran `mvn clean install` and I am getting the following errors. The errors include like AvoidStarImport, ImportOrder, WhitespaceAround, ArrayTypeStyle and NeedBraces and many more. It is working in IntelliJ and java syntax is correct, what changes do I need to make?

I cloned the project [Crawler4J](https://github.com/yasserg/crawler4j) and have used the default pom files.

```
[ERROR] /home/user/nutch/crawler4jParsar/crawler4j/crawler4j/src/main/java/edu/uci/ics/crawler4j/company/BCAusParser.java:3: Using the '.*' form of import should be avoided - java.io.*. [AvoidStarImport]
[ERROR] /home/user/nutch/crawler4jParsar/crawler4j/crawler4j/src/main/java/edu/uci/ics/crawler4j/company/BCAusParser.java:10: Wrong order for 'org.json.JSONException' import. [ImportOrder]
[ERROR] /home/user/nutch/crawler4jParsar/crawler4j/crawler4j/src/main/java/edu/uci/ics/crawler4j/company/BCAusParser.java:23:14: 'while' is not followed by whitespace. [WhitespaceAround]
[ERROR] /home/user/nutch/crawler4jParsar/crawler4j/crawler4j/src/main/java/edu/uci/ics/crawler4j/company/BCAusParser.java:24:9: '{' at column 9 should be on the previous line. [LeftCurly]
[ERROR] /home/user/nutch/crawler4jParsar/crawler4j/crawler4j/src/main/java/edu/uci/ics/crawler4j/company/BCAusParser.java:51:31: Array brackets at illegal position. [ArrayTypeStyle]
[ERROR] /home/user/nutch/crawler4jParsar/crawler4j/crawler4j/src/main/java/edu/uci/ics/crawler4j/company/BCAusParser.java:110: 'if' construct must use '{}'s. [NeedBraces]
[ERROR] /home/user/nutch/crawler4jParsar/crawler4j/crawler4j/src/main/java/edu/uci/ics/crawler4j/company/BCAusParser.java:118: 'else' construct must use '{}'s. [NeedBraces]
[ERROR] /home/user/nutch/crawler4jParsar/crawler4j/crawler4j/src/main/java/edu/uci/ics/crawler4j/company/BCAusParser.java:129: Line is longer than 120 characters (found 162). [LineLength]
[ERROR] /home/user/nutch/crawler4jParsar/crawler4j/crawler4j/src/main/java/edu/uci/ics/crawler4j/company/BCAusParser.java:129:149: ',' is not followed by whitespace. [WhitespaceAfter]
[ERROR] /home/user/nutch/crawler4jParsar/crawler4j/crawler4j/src/main/java/edu/uci/ics/crawler4j/company/BCAusParser.java:136: Line is longer than 120 characters (found 148). [LineLength]
[ERROR] /home/user/nutch/crawler4jParsar/crawler4j/crawler4j/src/main/java/edu/uci/ics/crawler4j/company/UserPost.java:10:12: Name 'is_post' must match pattern '^[a-z][a-zA-Z0-9]*$'. [MemberName]
[ERROR] /home/user/nutch/crawler4jParsar/crawler4j/crawler4j/src/main/java/edu/uci/ics/crawler4j/company/UserPost.java:12:12: Name 'member_id' must match pattern '^[a-z][a-zA-Z0-9]*$'. [MemberName]
[ERROR] /home/user/nutch/crawler4jParsar/crawler4j/crawler4j/src/main/java/edu/uci/ics/crawler4j/company/UserPost.java:21:12: Name 'is_edit' must match pattern '^[a-z][a-zA-Z0-9]*$'. [MemberName]
[ERROR] /home/user/nutch/crawler4jParsar/crawler4j/crawler4j/src/main/java/edu/uci/ics/crawler4j/company/UserPost.java:25:12: Name 'message_raw' must match pattern '^[a-z][a-zA-Z0-9]*$'. [MemberName]
[ERROR] /home/user/nutch/crawler4jParsar/crawler4j/crawler4j/src/main/java/edu/uci/ics/crawler4j/company/UserPost.java:27:19: Name 'getMessage_raw' must match pattern '^[a-z][a-zA-Z0-9]*$'. [MethodName]
[ERROR] /home/user/nutch/crawler4jParsar/crawler4j/crawler4j/src/main/java/edu/uci/ics/crawler4j/company/UserPost.java:31:17: Name 'setMessage_raw' must match pattern '^[a-z][a-zA-Z0-9]*$'. [MethodName]
[ERROR] /home/user/nutch/crawler4jParsar/crawler4j/crawler4j/src/main/java/edu/uci/ics/crawler4j/company/UserPost.java:31:39: Name 'message_raw' must match pattern '^[a-z][a-zA-Z0-9]*$'. [ParameterName]
[ERROR] /home/user/nutch/crawler4jParsar/crawler4j/crawler4j/src/main/java/edu/uci/ics/crawler4j/company/UserPost.java:51:19: Name 'getIs_edit' must match pattern '^[a-z][a-zA-Z0-9]*$'. [MethodName]
[ERROR] /home/user/nutch/crawler4jParsar/crawler4j/crawler4j/src/main/java/edu/uci/ics/crawler4j/company/UserPost.java:55:17: Name 'setIs_edit' must match pattern '^[a-z][a-zA-Z0-9]*$'. [MethodName]
[ERROR] /home/user/nutch/crawler4jParsar/crawler4j/crawler4j/src/main/java/edu/uci/ics/crawler4j/company/UserPost.java:55:35: Name 'is_edit' must match pattern '^[a-z][a-zA-Z0-9]*$'. [ParameterName]
[ERROR] /home/user/nutch/crawler4jParsar/crawler4j/crawler4j/src/main/java/edu/uci/ics/crawler4j/company/UserPost.java:147:19: Name 'getIs_post' must match pattern '^[a-z][a-zA-Z0-9]*$'. [MethodName]
[ERROR] /home/user/nutch/crawler4jParsar/crawler4j/crawler4j/src/main/java/edu/uci/ics/crawler4j/company/UserPost.java:151:17: Name 'setIs_post' must match pattern '^[a-z][a-zA-Z0-9]*$'. [MethodName]
[ERROR] /home/user/nutch/crawler4jParsar/crawler4j/crawler4j/src/main/java/edu/uci/ics/crawler4j/company/UserPost.java:151:35: Name 'is_post' must match pattern '^[a-z][a-zA-Z0-9]*$'. [ParameterName]
[ERROR] /home/user/nutch/crawler4jParsar/crawler4j/crawler4j/src/main/java/edu/uci/ics/crawler4j/company/UserPost.java:163:19: Name 'getMember_id' must match pattern '^[a-z][a-zA-Z0-9]*$'. [MethodName]
[ERROR] /home/user/nutch/crawler4jParsar/crawler4j/crawler4j/src/main/java/edu/uci/ics/crawler4j/company/UserPost.java:167:17: Name 'setMember_id' must match pattern '^[a-z][a-zA-Z0-9]*$'. [MethodName]
[ERROR] /home/user/nutch/crawler4jParsar/crawler4j/crawler4j/src/main/java/edu/uci/ics/crawler4j/company/UserPost.java:167:37: Name 'member_id' must match pattern '^[a-z][a-zA-Z0-9]*$'. [ParameterName]
[ERROR] /home/user/nutch/crawler4jParsar/crawler4j/crawler4j/src/main/java/edu/uci/ics/crawler4j/company/Controller.java:5:8: Unused import - edu.uci.ics.crawler4j.crawler.Page. [UnusedImports]
[ERROR] /home/user/nutch/crawler4jParsar/crawler4j/crawler4j/src/main/java/edu/uci/ics/crawler4j/company/Controller.java:6:8: Unused import - edu.uci.ics.crawler4j.fetcher.PageFetchResult. [UnusedImports]
[ERROR] /home/user/nutch/crawler4jParsar/crawler4j/crawler4j/src/main/java/edu/uci/ics/crawler4j/company/Controller.java:10:8: Unused import - edu.uci.ics.crawler4j.url.WebURL. [UnusedImports]
[ERROR] /home/user/nutch/crawler4jParsar/crawler4j/crawler4j/src/main/java/edu/uci/ics/crawler4j/company/Controller.java:12: Wrong order for 'java.io.File' import. [ImportOrder]
[ERROR] /home/user/nutch/crawler4jParsar/crawler4j/crawler4j/src/main/java/edu/uci/ics/crawler4j/company/DataProcess.java:3:8: Unused import - org.json.JSONArray. [UnusedImports]
[ERROR] /home/user/nutch/crawler4jParsar/crawler4j/crawler4j/src/main/java/edu/uci/ics/crawler4j/company/DataProcess.java:6: Using the '.*' form of import should be avoided - java.io.*. [AvoidStarImport]
[ERROR] /home/user/nutch/crawler4jParsar/crawler4j/crawler4j/src/main/java/edu/uci/ics/crawler4j/company/DataProcess.java:6: Wrong order for 'java.io.*' import. [ImportOrder]
[ERROR] /home/user/nutch/crawler4jParsar/crawler4j/crawler4j/src/main/java/edu/uci/ics/crawler4j/company/DataProcess.java:13:13: Declaring variables, return values or parameters of type 'HashSet' is not allowed. [IllegalType]
[ERROR] /home/user/nutch/crawler4jParsar/crawler4j/crawler4j/src/main/java/edu/uci/ics/crawler4j/company/DataProcess.java:13:29: Name 'unique_system_id' must match pattern '^[a-z][a-zA-Z0-9]*$'. [LocalVariableName]
[ERROR] /home/user/nutch/crawler4jParsar/crawler4j/crawler4j/src/main/java/edu/uci/ics/crawler4j/company/DataProcess.java:14:31: Name 'final_data' must match pattern '^[a-z][a-zA-Z0-9]*$'. [LocalVariableName]
[ERROR] /home/user/nutch/crawler4jParsar/crawler4j/crawler4j/src/main/java/edu/uci/ics/crawler4j/company/DataProcess.java:19:24: Name 'system_id' must match pattern '^[a-z][a-zA-Z0-9]*$'. [LocalVariableName]
[ERROR] /home/user/nutch/crawler4jParsar/crawler4j/crawler4j/src/main/java/edu/uci/ics/crawler4j/company/DataProcess.java:59:40: Array brackets at illegal position. [ArrayTypeStyle]
[ERROR] /home/user/nutch/crawler4jParsar/crawler4j/crawler4j/src/main/java/edu/uci/ics/crawler4j/company/User.java:6: Wrong order for 'java.util.HashMap' import. [ImportOrder]
[ERROR] /home/user/nutch/crawler4jParsar/crawler4j/crawler4j/src/main/java/edu/uci/ics/crawler4j/company/User.java:11:12: Name 'is_post' must match pattern '^[a-z][a-zA-Z0-9]*$'. [MemberName]
[ERROR] /home/user/nutch/crawler4jParsar/crawler4j/crawler4j/src/main/java/edu/uci/ics/crawler4j/company/User.java:14:12: Name 'member_id' must match pattern '^[a-z][a-zA-Z0-9]*$'. [MemberName]
[ERROR] /home/user/nutch/crawler4jParsar/crawler4j/crawler4j/src/main/java/edu/uci/ics/crawler4j/company/User.java:19:12: Name 'Diagnosis' must match pattern '^[a-z][a-zA-Z0-9]*$'. [MemberName]
[ERROR] /home/user/nutch/crawler4jParsar/crawler4j/crawler4j/src/main/java/edu/uci/ics/crawler4j/company/User.java:22:12: Name 'Diagnosis_Diagnosed' must match pattern '^[a-z][a-zA-Z0-9]*$'. [MemberName]
[ERROR] /home/user/nutch/crawler4jParsar/crawler4j/crawler4j/src/main/java/edu/uci/ics/crawler4j/company/User.java:24:12: Name 'Diagnosis_Type' must match pattern '^[a-z][a-zA-Z0-9]*$'. [MemberName]
[ERROR] /home/user/nutch/crawler4jParsar/crawler4j/crawler4j/src/main/java/edu/uci/ics/crawler4j/company/User.java:26:12: Name 'Diagnosis_Recurrent' must match pattern '^[a-z][a-zA-Z0-9]*$'. [MemberName]
[ERROR] /home/user/nutch/crawler4jParsar/crawler4j/crawler4j/src/main/java/edu/uci/ics/crawler4j/company/User.java:28:12: Name 'Diagnosis_Metastatic' must match pattern '^[a-z][a-zA-Z0-9]*$'. [MemberName]
[ERROR] /home/user/nutch/crawler4jParsar/crawler4j/crawler4j/src/main/java/edu/uci/ics/crawler4j/company/User.java:30:12: Name 'Diagnosis_Stage' must match pattern '^[a-z][a-zA-Z0-9]*$'. [MemberName]
[ERROR] /home/user/nutch/crawler4jParsar/crawler4j/crawler4j/src/main/java/edu/uci/ics/crawler4j/company/User.java:32:12: Name 'Diagnosis_Lymph_Nodes_Removed' must match pattern '^[a-z][a-zA-Z0-9]*$'. [MemberName]
[ERROR] /home/user/nutch/crawler4jParsar/crawler4j/crawler4j/src/main/java/edu/uci/ics/crawler4j/company/User.java:34:12: Name 'Diagnosis_Positive_Lymph_Nodes' must match pattern '^[a-z][a-zA-Z0-9]*$'. [MemberName]
[ERROR] /home/user/nutch/crawler4jParsar/crawler4j/crawler4j/src/main/java/edu/uci/ics/crawler4j/company/User.java:36:12: Name 'Diagnosis_Tumor_Size' must match pattern '^[a-z][a-zA-Z0-9]*$'. [MemberName]
[ERROR] /home/user/nutch/crawler4jParsar/crawler4j/crawler4j/src/main/java/edu/uci/ics/crawler4j/company/User.java:38:12: Name 'Diagnosis_Tumor_Grade' must match pattern '^[a-z][a-zA-Z0-9]*$'. [MemberName]
[ERROR] /home/user/nutch/crawler4jParsar/crawler4j/crawler4j/src/main/java/edu/uci/ics/crawler4j/company/User.java:43:12: Name 'Diagnosis_Hormone_Receptor_Status' must match pattern '^[a-z][a-zA-Z0-9]*$'. [MemberName]
[ERROR] /home/user/nutch/crawler4jParsar/crawler4j/crawler4j/src/main/java/edu/uci/ics/crawler4j/company/User.java:45:12: Name 'Diagnosis_HER2_neu_Status' must match pattern '^[a-z][a-zA-Z0-9]*$'. [MemberName]
[ERROR] /home/user/nutch/crawler4jParsar/crawler4j/crawler4j/src/main/java/edu/uci/ics/crawler4j/company/User.java:47:12: Name 'Treatment_Chemotherapy' must match pattern '^[a-z][a-zA-Z0-9]*$'. [MemberName]
[ERROR] /home/user/nutch/crawler4jParsar/crawler4j/crawler4j/src/main/java/edu/uci/ics/crawler4j/company/User.java:49:12: Name 'Treatment_Targeted_Therapy' must match pattern '^[a-z][a-zA-Z0-9]*$'. [MemberName]
[ERROR] /home/user/nutch/crawler4jParsar/crawler4j/crawler4j/src/main/java/edu/uci/ics/crawler4j/company/User.java:51:12: Name 'Treatment_Hormonal_Therapy' must match pattern '^[a-z][a-zA-Z0-9]*$'. [MemberName]
[ERROR] /home/user/nutch/crawler4jParsar/crawler4j/crawler4j/src/main/java/edu/uci/ics/crawler4j/company/User.java:53:12: Name 'Treatment_Radiation_Therapy' must match pattern '^[a-z][a-zA-Z0-9]*$'. [MemberName]
[ERROR] /home/user/nutch/crawler4jParsar/crawler4j/crawler4j/src/main/java/edu/uci/ics/crawler4j/company/User.java:55:12: Name 'Treatment_Surgery' must match pattern '^[a-z][a-zA-Z0-9]*$'. [MemberName]
[ERROR] /home/user/nutch/crawler4jParsar/crawler4j/crawler4j/src/main/java/edu/uci/ics/crawler4j/company/User.java:57:19: Name 'getIs_post' must match pattern '^[a-z][a-zA-Z0-9]*$'. [MethodName]
[ERROR] /home/user/nutch/crawler4jParsar/crawler4j/crawler4j/src/main/java/edu/uci/ics/crawler4j/company/User.java:61:17: Name 'setIs_post' must match pattern '^[a-z][a-zA-Z0-9]*$'. [MethodName]
[ERROR] /home/user/nutch/crawler4jParsar/crawler4j/crawler4j/src/main/java/edu/uci/ics/crawler4j/company/User.java:61:35: Name 'is_post' must match pattern '^[a-z][a-zA-Z0-9]*$'. [ParameterName]
[ERROR] /home/user/nutch/crawler4jParsar/crawler4j/crawler4j/src/main/java/edu/uci/ics/crawler4j/company/User.java:81:19: Name 'getMember_id' must match pattern '^[a-z][a-zA-Z0-9]*$'. [MethodName]
[ERROR] /home/user/nutch/crawler4jParsar/crawler4j/crawler4j/src/main/java/edu/uci/ics/crawler4j/company/User.java:85:17: Name 'setMember_id' must match pattern '^[a-z][a-zA-Z0-9]*$'. [MethodName]
[ERROR] /home/user/nutch/crawler4jParsar/crawler4j/crawler4j/src/main/java/edu/uci/ics/crawler4j/company/User.java:85:37: Name 'member_id' must match pattern '^[a-z][a-zA-Z0-9]*$'. [ParameterName]
[ERROR] /home/user/nutch/crawler4jParsar/crawler4j/crawler4j/src/main/java/edu/uci/ics/crawler4j/company/User.java:294:36: Name 'post_url' must match pattern '^[a-z][a-zA-Z0-9]*$'. [ParameterName]
[ERROR] /home/user/nutch/crawler4jParsar/crawler4j/crawler4j/src/main/java/edu/uci/ics/crawler4j/company/CustomParser.java:22: 'if' construct must use '{}'s. [NeedBraces]
[ERROR] /home/user/nutch/crawler4jParsar/crawler4j/crawler4j/src/main/java/edu/uci/ics/crawler4j/company/CustomParser.java:69:24: Name 'ailment_domain' must match pattern '^[a-z][a-zA-Z0-9]*$'. [LocalVariableName]
[ERROR] /home/user/nutch/crawler4jParsar/crawler4j/crawler4j/src/main/java/edu/uci/ics/crawler4j/company/CustomParser.java:75:24: Name 'ailment_domain' must match pattern '^[a-z][a-zA-Z0-9]*$'. [LocalVariableName]
[ERROR] /home/user/nutch/crawler4jParsar/crawler4j/crawler4j/src/main/java/edu/uci/ics/crawler4j/company/CustomParser.java:87:59: Name 'ailment_domain' must match pattern '^[a-z][a-zA-Z0-9]*$'. [ParameterName]
[ERROR] /home/user/nutch/crawler4jParsar/crawler4j/crawler4j/src/main/java/edu/uci/ics/crawler4j/company/CustomParser.java:143: 'if' construct must use '{}'s. [NeedBraces]
[ERROR] /home/user/nutch/crawler4jParsar/crawler4j/crawler4j/src/main/java/edu/uci/ics/crawler4j/company/CustomParser.java:202: 'if' construct must use '{}'s. [NeedBraces]
[ERROR] /home/user/nutch/crawler4jParsar/crawler4j/crawler4j/src/main/java/edu/uci/ics/crawler4j/company/CustomParser.java:204: 'else' construct must use '{}'s. [NeedBraces]
[ERROR] /home/user/nutch/crawler4jParsar/crawler4j/crawler4j/src/main/java/edu/uci/ics/crawler4j/company/CustomParser.java:214: 'if' construct must use '{}'s. [NeedBraces]
[ERROR] /home/user/nutch/crawler4jParsar/crawler4j/crawler4j/src/main/java/edu/uci/ics/crawler4j/company/CustomParser.java:216: 'else' construct must use '{}'s. [NeedBraces]
[ERROR] /home/user/nutch/crawler4jParsar/crawler4j/crawler4j/src/main/java/edu/uci/ics/crawler4j/company/CustomParser.java:271: 'if' construct must use '{}'s. [NeedBraces]
[ERROR] /home/user/nutch/crawler4jParsar/crawler4j/crawler4j/src/main/java/edu/uci/ics/crawler4j/company/CustomParser.java:292: 'if' construct must use '{}'s. [NeedBraces]
[ERROR] /home/user/nutch/crawler4jParsar/crawler4j/crawler4j/src/main/java/edu/uci/ics/crawler4j/company/MyCrawler.java:7: Wrong order for 'org.json.JSONArray' import. [ImportOrder]
[ERROR] /home/user/nutch/crawler4jParsar/crawler4j/crawler4j/src/main/java/edu/uci/ics/crawler4j/company/MyCrawler.java:10: Wrong order for 'java.io.File' import. [ImportOrder]
[ERROR] /home/user/nutch/crawler4jParsar/crawler4j/crawler4j/src/main/java/edu/uci/ics/crawler4j/company/MyCrawler.java:10:8: Unused import - java.io.File. [UnusedImports]
[ERROR] /home/user/nutch/crawler4jParsar/crawler4j/crawler4j/src/main/java/edu/uci/ics/crawler4j/company/MyCrawler.java:18:19: 'static' modifier out of order with the JLS suggestions. [ModifierOrder]
[ERROR] /home/user/nutch/crawler4jParsar/crawler4j/crawler4j/src/main/java/edu/uci/ics/crawler4j/company/MyCrawler.java:35: 'if' construct must use '{}'s. [NeedBraces]
[ERROR] /home/user/nutch/crawler4jParsar/crawler4j/crawler4j/src/main/java/edu/uci/ics/crawler4j/company/MyCrawler.java:38:13: Name 'page_number_of_topics' must match pattern '^[a-z][a-zA-Z0-9]*$'. [LocalVariableName]
[ERROR] /home/user/nutch/crawler4jParsar/crawler4j/crawler4j/src/main/java/edu/uci/ics/crawler4j/company/MyCrawler.java:39:13: Name 'page_number_of_replies' must match pattern '^[a-z][a-zA-Z0-9]*$'. [LocalVariableName]
[ERROR] /home/user/nutch/crawler4jParsar/crawler4j/crawler4j/src/main/java/edu/uci/ics/crawler4j/company/MyCrawler.java:43:20: Name 'page_number' must match pattern '^[a-z][a-zA-Z0-9]*$'. [LocalVariableName]
[ERROR] /home/user/nutch/crawler4jParsar/crawler4j/crawler4j/src/main/java/edu/uci/ics/crawler4j/company/MyCrawler.java:50:20: Name 'page_number' must match pattern '^[a-z][a-zA-Z0-9]*$'. [LocalVariableName]
[ERROR] /home/user/nutch/crawler4jParsar/crawler4j/crawler4j/src/main/java/edu/uci/ics/crawler4j/company/MyCrawler.java:58: Line is longer than 120 characters (found 122). [LineLength]
[ERROR] /home/user/nutch/crawler4jParsar/crawler4j/crawler4j/src/main/java/edu/uci/ics/crawler4j/company/MyCrawler.java:87:83: ')' is preceded with whitespace. [ParenPad]
```

Comment: the problem is about java files. have you read the errors and adapted the code?

Comment: These are checkstyle errors. Did you try disabling it?

Comment: @Stultuske I am getting error on approximately every line(i have reduced it for stackoverflow). The code is working fine without making a jar. How do i adapt to this `Wrong order for 'org.json.JSONException' import. [ImportOrder]`, how do i import this

Comment: Your maven build seems to do some code-style checking. So while the syntax is basically correct the coding-style doesn't match some styleguide that are enforced somwhere in the pom-files...

Comment: @gc7 Did you read my comment?

Comment: @BackSlash yeah just now, i will try disabling checkstyle

Comment: I agree with @BackSlash it looks like you are running a sonar (probably similar) style-check. I am curious, however, how the author manages to build it with the same checks.

Comment: yes, there was some kind of checkstyle `<artifactId>maven-checkstyle-plugin</artifactId>` , i removed it using `mvn clean install -Dcheckstyle.skip` and it was successful.

Answer (score 1):

Googling one of the errors and inspecting the POM shows that Crawler4J uses the [maven-checkstyle-plugin](https://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-checkstyle-plugin/) (like [BackSlash](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1759845/backslash) already mentioned).

The style will be checked during compilation (see POM). You could change the POM locally by changing the line containing `<failsOnError>true</failsOnError>` to `false`, but I would discourage it if you want to contribute to the project.